# Can you code sign executable files like bash scripts?

Tags: macos, bash

I'm distributing a .command file. When it's opened after being downloaded, I get a message saying it's from an unsigned developer. So, I know I can code sign apps, but can I code sign my script?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To my knowledge, the only way to do this is to wrap your script in Applescript, and thereby convert it into an App.
You can then sign it normally.

Arguably, the users who care about this want it to be a clickable app or droplet or similar (i.e. GUI triggered), and those who are using the script through the shell should be using a `.sh` version of the file and not care.

Comment: This answer is not quite correct. You can indeed code-sign scripts by doing the following: codesign --force --sign 'Developer ID Application: YourDeveloperIDName' -i 'bundleID' 'PATH TO SCRIPT'. You will need to preserve the script's extended attributes to maintain the code signature. Another way to satisfy Gatekeeper is by distributing your script in a XIP archive rather than a XIP archive.

Comment: @Draxillion can you use that same codesign code inside a bash script file or does it need to be Applescript specifically? I need to have one of my bash scripts get past Gatekeeper so that it can move files in the correct directories.

Comment: @Draxillion XIP archive rather than a XIP archive?